# Returning Value From Callback in a Map

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

My problem is depending on the result of an asynchronous operation during a map. I know similar questions have been asked, but cannot quite figure out how to apply this to my case.

I have figured out how to solve my problem using synchronous methods, my code is as follows,

```
    if (store.store !== {}) {
      const files = Object.values(store.store).map((file, index) => {
        return fs.existsSync(file.fileName) ? file : FILES[index]; 
      });
    }
```

I want to try writing this using asynchronous callbacks. I am new to javascript and just want to get the hang of these callbacks, this is what I tried, but it obviously does not work.

```
if (store.store !== {}) {
  const exists = (path: string) => {
    return fs.access(path, fs.constants.F_OK, (e) => {
      return e ? false : true;
    });
  };
  const files = Object.values(store.store).map((file, index) => {
    return exists(file.fileName)? file : FILES[index];
  });
```

I assume during execution the code does not wait for the result of the call back. However, using async/await with fs.promises.access does not work because I think the map function doesn't work asynchronously. Anyways, I want to be able to do this without async/await, is there any way to do this?

Comment: You can use promises with `map`, you just end up with an array of promises, which you can then pass to `Promise.all()`.

Comment: I will give that a shot. Although I'm interested in knowing how to solve this problem without promises at all and just callbacks.

Comment: If you want to call parallel async function and handle the async behavior with callbacks, you will essentially have to reinvent promises so you can keep track of the state of each callback. It's hard to imagine why you would want to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED SOLUTION:
Easy way: wrap the below solution in a Promise:

```js
const getAuthorizedFiles => storeObj => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const doneCount = Object.keys(storeObj).length;

  if (doneCount === 0) {
    reject();
  } else {
    const files = [];
    let count = 0;

    Object.values(storeObj).forEach((file, index) => {
      fs.access(file.fileName, fs.constants.F_OK, err => {
        files[index] = !err ? file : null;
        count += 1;
        if (count === doneCount) {
          resolve(files);
        }
      });
    });
  }
});

// Implementation:
getAuthorizedFiles(store.store).then(files => { console.log(files[0]); });
```

If OP just really doesn't want to deal with Promises for some reason, (though they are now a part of the spec) then they can also just make their own fun callback pattern function:

```js
const getAuthorizedFiles = (storeObj, cb) => {
  if (typeof cb !== 'function') { cb = x => x; }
  
  const doneCount = Object.keys(storeObj).length;

  if (doneCount === 0) {
    cb(new Error(`I don't want to deal with an empty object`));
  } else {
    const files = [];
    let count = 0;

    Object.values(storeObj).forEach((file, index) => {
      fs.access(file.fileName, fs.constants.F_OK, err => {
        files[index] = !err ? file : null;
        count += 1;
        if (count === doneCount) {
          cb(null, files);
        }
      });
    });
  }
};

// Implementation:
getAuthorizedFiles(store.store, files => { console.log(files[0]); });
```

ORIGINAL SOLUTION:

This is a simple way to do it without async/await. Set the `files` value as an empty array. Swap out the `.map` for a `.forEach` so you are no longer concerned with trying to return some value from an asynchronous function. Sounds like order is important, so when the `access` callback resolves, assign the file from the `store.store` Array into the new `files` Array.

```js
if (store.store !== {}) {
  const files = [];

  Object.values(store.store).forEach((file, index) => {
    fs.access(file.fileName, fs.constants.F_OK, err => {
      files[index] = !err ? file : null;
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: This will put the value null at the corresponding index from your original array where the access call resolved with an error. If order isn't important, then you can just push the "file" value to the "files" Array when the callback is called without an error.

Comment: Cool I just wanted to get an idea of how to approach without async/await, this really helps. ty

Comment: How will you know **when** you can access `files`? If you try `files[0]` after the `forEach` runs, the callbacks will not have completed. This doesn't solve the problem *at all*. Also, `store.store !== {}` will **always** be true.

Comment: You're right. There must be a vanilla way to do this though right or are promises my only recourse? I guess I will try to do it with promises.access.

Comment: I guess I assumed OP would be handling when they can access the files Array, since using Promises requires passing a cb to the .then method, and using async/await requires wrapping in a function.

Comment: Don't write your own promise logic here, though. Just use `fs.promises` and `Promise.all`.

Answer (score 1):

fs.access as a third argument supports callback which means it is not returned back when fs.access is called, but you can make promise with primisify util

```
const access = util.promisify(fs.access);
```

then you can create async exists method utilizing then/catch to determine if you have access permission to the file

```
const asyncExists = (file) => {
  return access(file.fileName, fs.constants.F_OK).then(() => file).catch(() => null);
};
```

and at the end you can map files to the array of promises and wrap it into Promise.all() to wait until all promises are resolved

```
Promise.all(Object.values(store.store).map(file => asyncExists(file))).filter(f => f != null)
  .then(files => {
    // Now you have array of files that you have access to it
  });
```

Comment: At least since Node 10, we have has  [`fs.Promises.access`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_access_path_mode), which the OP mentioned. `util.promisify` probably isn't needed.